# Default window instance in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have application with Form1 that is the registration form and Form2 is the actual application. I need when the application is registered, no longer opens Form1 than just Form2.
I convert this code from vb.net to c # and it works well in windowforms applications, but I have a problem with a WPF application - double ** line. I am beginner with WPF. Can anybody help me, please?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Added to support default instance behavour in C#
        if (defaultInstance == null)
            defaultInstance = this;
    }
#region Default Instance
private static Form1 defaultInstance;
 public static Form1 Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultInstance == null)
            {
                defaultInstance = new Form1();
                **defaultInstance.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(defaultInstance_FormClosed);**
            }

            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    static void defaultInstance_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        defaultInstance = null;
    }
#endregion //Default Instance
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is FormClosedEventHandler in WPF, this code works fine in WinForms.

Comment: I understand that's the line that's causing the problem, but I don't understand what the problem *is*. Explain what is happening; does it not compile? Does it give an exception at runtime? Or is it simply not doing what you expect?

Comment: I'm trying to make instead of Winforms, WPF windows to do the same.

Comment: That's not a problem that's a task/requirement

Comment: Is Form1 of type Window?

Comment: It not compile. Form1 is in Winforms. In WPF is Window named Validation, but code is the same. Error is - 'Validation' does not contain a definition for 'FormClosed' and no extension method 'FormClosed' accepting a first argument of type 'Validation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Window.Closed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thank you, Charles, you opened my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found a solution. If someone needs it:

Line:

```
defaultInstance.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(defaultInstance_FormClosed);
```

replace with:

```
defaultInstance.Closed += new EventHandler(defaultInstance_WindowClosed);
```

and line:

```
static void defaultInstance_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
```

replace with:

```
static void defaultInstance_WindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And of course Form1 should be replaced with the real WPF window.

In my case the Form1 = Validation.